# SpringBoot Rest Service Exception Handling for a file Download

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

Currently I am building a RESTful SpringBoot Service and it's functionality is a file download.

Please let me know if there a way to handle exceptions and notify the client Eg : FileNotFound or IOExceptions.

The regular ExceptionMappers didn't work.
Sample code:

```
@GET
@RequestMapping("/fileDownload")
public FileSystemResource fileDownload(HttpServletResponse response) {
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream)
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=downloadZip");
enter code here
return new FileSystemResource(file);
```

Comment: have you aware of `@RestControllerAdvice` to handle exceptions https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: That works only for xml/json responses.

Comment: If file is available, you want to send file as response, if file is not available then what response you want to send?

Comment: FileNotFound, more or less like a 404.

Comment: In that case throw custom exception when file is not found and use `@RestControllerAdvice` to return 404 status code with custom error message

Answer (score 0):

You can use @RestControllerAdvice which is global exception handler for spring .
It should be a separate class with defining a list of exceptions and the way you handle them using @ExceptionHandler annotation 
Also you can set the package which will be scanned for controllers 
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = “your.controller.package”)
If you don’t define basePackages then all @Controller
in classpath will be scanned
If you want to handle exception in your @Controller or @RestController class you can define @ExceptionHandler on method and it will work too but exception will be only handled in the same controller , for example if you will define @ExceptionHandler in one controller it will handle it .
But if you will have the same exception thrown in another controller it would not handle it.
So if you have such case you should better use @ControllerAdvice or @RestControllerAdvice it will handle exceptions globally .